# Кастомная цветовая палитра для Color Picker на iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

Нужно нарисовать вот такую цветовую палитру для ColorPicker в iOS-приложении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Составляющие цвета здесь явно меняются по какой-то схеме, потому что эта палитра выглядит однотипно в разных источниках. Подскажите по какому алгоритму меняются компоненты цвета при отрисовке палитры такого вида?